# How to insert <img> inside an <a> with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am playing with some JSON data. With following JavaScript, I can retrieve some links.

```js
(function() {
    var flickrAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON( flickrAPI, {
    id: "132455232@N07",
    lang: "en-us",
    format: "json"
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
        console.log(data.items[i]['link']);
        if ( i === 5 ) {
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And with the following JavaScript I can get some images:

```js
(function() {
    var flickrAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON( flickrAPI, {
    id: "132455232@N07",
    lang: "en-us",
    format: "json"
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
        $( "<img>" ).attr( "src", item.media.m ).appendTo( "#images" );
        if ( i === 5 ) {
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  img {
    height: 159px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
  } 
</style>

<div id="images"></div>
```

Well I am beginner to jQuery, I have tried looking in jQuery docs about this problem but wasn't successful how to achieve it. I also tried doing it myself but was in vain.

Actually what I am trying to do is wrapping the image inside with the anchor, whose href being the links I am getting from first code.

Code in both the example are same except one line. I know my expected solution will also will be of one line merging both different lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the `wrap` function (http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) which does exactly what it's name suggests. It wraps an element with any html.

Check your edited code, I made a new variable called link (which is created the same way your image is created) and after appending the image to `#images` I call `wrap(link)`.

I think it's not a rock-solid solution because of performance lost. 
You could (and should) create an Array with strings instead and write it to the DOM all at once.

```js
(function() {
    var flickrAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON( flickrAPI, {
    id: "132455232@N07",
    lang: "en-us",
    format: "json"
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
        var image = $( "<img>" ).attr( "src", item.media.m )
        var link = $("<a>").attr("href", "//example.org");
        image.appendTo( "#images" ).wrap(link);
        if ( i === 5 ) {
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  img {
    height: 159px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
  } 
</style>

<div id="images"></div>
```

Here is a better solution to save some iterations:

```js
(function() {
    var flickrAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON( flickrAPI, {
    id: "132455232@N07",
    lang: "en-us",
    format: "json"
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
      var imagesHTML = [];
      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
        imagesHTML.push([
            "<a href='" + "http://example.org" + "'>",
                 "<img src='" + item.media.m + "'>",
            "</a>"
        ].join(""));
        if ( i === 5 ) {
          return false;
        }
      });
      $("#images").html(imagesHTML.join(""));
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  img {
    height: 159px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
  } 
</style>

<div id="images"></div>
```

It's a good way to minimize DOM interaction to a bare minimum because it's so slow. It won't matter much in your case but it's a good habit in general to use performant code.

Comment: Nice answer and explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
    var img = $( "<img>" ).attr( "src", item.media.m );
    var a= $( "<a>" ).attr( "href", item.media.m );
    img.appendTo(a);
    a.appendTo( "#images" );
    if ( i === 5 ) {
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Look for the right value in result for href.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing it:

```
(function() {
    var flickrAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON( flickrAPI, {
    id: "132455232@N07",
    lang: "en-us",
    format: "json"
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
        var html = '<a href="'+ item.media.m +'"><img src="'+ item.media.m  +'"/></a>';
        $(html).appendTo( "#images" );
        if ( i === 5 ) {
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
})();
```

You can just form the HTML in a string, and pass it to jQuery.

Comment: Good answer, but an explanation is useful ever

Answer (score 0):

Can you use .append() ?

```
.done(function( data ) {
  $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
    $( "#images" ).append('<a href="###YOURLINKHERE###"><img src="' + item.media.m + '" /></a>';
    if ( i === 5 ) {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```